# Server or Client is better for producing report

Tags: android, pdf, cordova, client-server

I want to create a phonegap application for android phones which will generate a pdf report.
I have to options, 
1)my phone(client) will generate pdf report with javascript
2)send data to server and will send back the report
   which choice is better? I believe second is better but i am not sure about the time that client will spend with this solution as i dont use server before,

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[client]` and `[server]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[client-server]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It mainly depends on 2 factors:
- *How many pdf will you generate ? 2 per day ? 1000 per seconds ?*
- *What is the complexity of the report ? A few text blocks ? many graphical assets ?*

If you don't have a lot of PDFs to generate, you can keep it serverside. If you have a lot of PDFs, you might have to try to do it client side with a low end device to see how long does it take to process it.

There's no clear cut answer for this, estimate your processing load and see where it'll be the more robust from a technical point of view and pleasing for your users.